# Get html into element attribute from include or variable in jade

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm using [Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com/)

I need to pass html to attribute `data-content` of a bootstrap tooltip.

Is there a way that I can capture the content of a include file into a variable?

Something like this php snippet?

```
ob_start();
include "vendedores.php";
$vendedores = ob_get_clean();
```

So far I've tried the following

Trying to include the partial

```
button.btn.btn-default(type='button'
    target="_blank"
    data-container="#producto-{{product.code}}"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="top"
    data-trigger="hover"
    data-content="include _vendedores"
    class="product-popover"
    data-html="true"
)

button.btn.btn-default(type='button'
    target="_blank"
    data-container="#producto-{{product.code}}"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="top"
    data-trigger="hover"
    data-content=include _vendedores
    class="product-popover"
    data-html="true"
)
```

Defining a mixin

```
mixin myInclude()
    include _vendedores

button.btn.btn-default(type='button'
    target="_blank"
    data-container="#producto-{{product.code}}"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="top"
    data-trigger="hover"
    data-content="+myInclude()"
    class="product-popover"
    data-html="true"
)
```

**EDIT**

This is my _vendedores.jade file

```
address
    strong Caracas, Zona Metropolitana
    br 
    abbr(title="teléfono") Tlf
    |   0XXX-XXXXXXX
address
    strong Gran Caracas (Oeste)
    br
    abbr(title="teléfono") Tlf
    |   0XXX-XXXXXXX
address
    strong Zona Centro (Occidente)
    br
    abbr(title="teléfono") Tlf
    |   0XXX-XXXXXXX
address
    strong Zona Occidente
    br 
    abbr(title="teléfono") Tlf
    |   0XXX-2757235
address
    strong Zona Oriente
    br 
    abbr(title="teléfono") Tlf
    |   0XXX-XXXXXXX
```

---

For now I'm using a variable like this

```
- var vendedores = "<address><strong>Caracas, Zona Metropolitana</strong><br><abbr title='teléfono'>Tlf</abbr>  0XXX-XXXXXXX</address><address><strong>Gran Caracas (Oeste)</strong><br><abbr title='teléfono'>Tlf</abbr> 0XXX-XXXXXXX</address><address><strong>Zona Centro (Occidente)</strong><br><abbr title='teléfono'>Tlf</abbr>  0XXX-XXXXXXX</address><address><strong>Zona Occidente</strong><br><abbr title='teléfono'>Tlf</abbr> 0XXX-XXXXXXX</address><address><strong>Zona Oriente</strong><br><abbr title='teléfono'>Tlf</abbr> 0XXX-XXXXXXX</address>"
```

and `data-content!='#{vendedores}'`

Ugly! I know...

Comment: how your **_vendedores** file looks like?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Jade is a template engine, your _vendedores file looks like a database.

I would write a mixin and pass the data (name and telephone number) as a parameter:

```
mixin button(name, phone)
  - var address = "<address><strong>"+name+"</strong><br/><abbr title='teléfono'>Tlf</abbr>"+phone+"</address>"
  button.btn.btn-default(type='button'
    target="_blank"
    data-container="#producto-{{product.code}}"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="top"
    data-trigger="hover"
    data-content!=address
    class="product-popover"
    data-html="true"
  )

+button("Caracas, Zona Metropolitana", "12345")
```